# IReport - HQL with MSSQL

Tags: jdbc, hive, ireport

Unfortunately, the last code that I wrote was `Fortran4 @ ‘86th`. Anyway, the life is unpredictable, and now I have to edit several jasper reports so digging for more than a week. I could manage well with **t-sql** but the **HQL** is my first try.

I have several reports running on `tomtsat6` and connected to `MSSQL server` via `jdbc4`.

There is one main report definition `jrxml` file and several `xml's` with contains the inputs parameters, columns to display and the Hive query.

I add all of the custom `classpath's` in `option->classpath` (one of them contains the `hibernate.cfg.xml` and I set it on the top) so:

- If I connect straight to the MSSQL DB the Hive dialect is in correct.
- If try Hiberbate connection I’m getting the “/hibernate.cfg.xml not found”

So, my question is how the set the iReport environment so the execute the Hive query where connected to MSSQL via jdbc ?  All I need is to be able to execute а Hive QL query.

Any help will be highly appreciated!

Thank you very much

Comment: Please add your code.

Comment: BTW - I do not know what the code will help - I need to set iReport to use MSSQL and work with HiveQL language.

first question is - where the hibernate.cfg.xml should stay ? I set log4j in 'DEBUG' level but all I got is "Configuration resource: /hibernate.cfg.xml"